# how to read haskell type signature?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

So I put this statement on my ghci

```
jkl x f y = f (map (+y) x)
```

And I got this out put back.

```
jkl :: Num b => [b] -> ([b] -> t) -> b -> t
```

But I'm confused when I read it. From my understanding jkl is type num that takes [b], [b] and t, and b. in the end it will output t. is that the right way to read it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
jkl :: Num b => [b] -> ([b] -> t) -> b -> t
```

Whoever calls `jkl` has to

- choose types `b` and `t`
- guarantee that `b` was chosen among numeric types (the `Num b` constraint)
- pass a `[b]` (list of `b`) as first argument
- pass a function `[b] -> t` as second argument (i.e. taking `[b]` and returning a `t`)
- pass a `b` as third argument
- receive `t` back as a final result

Answer (score 7):

Whatever is between the double colon `::` and the fat arrow `=>` is called *constraints*. In this case, you have one constraint: `Num b`. This constraint demands that, whatever type `b` turns out to be, it must be an instance of type class `Num`.

After the fat arrow, you get types of function parameters, and at the very end type of its result.

Parameters:

1. `[b]` - a list of values of type `b`, whatever that is.
2. `[b] -> t` - a function that takes a list of `b` and produces a single `t`.
3. `b` - a single value of type `b`.

And finally, function result is `t`.